# How to properly run consecutive tests querying a Flask-SQLAlchemy database?

Tags: python, unit-testing, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-testing

I'm setting up unit-testing for a Flask project using SQLAlchemy as ORM. For my tests I need to setup a new test database every time I run a single unit-test. Somehow, I cannot seem to run consecutive tests that query the database, even though if I run these tests in isolation they succeed.

I use the `flask-testing` package, and follow their documentation [here](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Testing/).

Here is a working example to illustrate the problem:

`app.py:`

```py
from flask import Flask


def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    return app


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = create_app()
    app.run(port=8080)
```

`database.py:`

```py
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

db = SQLAlchemy()
```

`models.py:`

```py
from database import db


class TestModel(db.Model):
    """Model for testing."""

    __tablename__ = 'test_models'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer,
                   primary_key=True
                   )
```

`test/__init__.py:`

```py
from flask_testing import TestCase

from app import create_app
from database import db


class BaseTestCase(TestCase):
    def create_app(self):
        app = create_app()
        app.config.update({
            'SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI': 'sqlite:///:memory:',
            'SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS': False,
            'TESTING': True
        })
        db.init_app(app)
        return app

    def setUp(self):
        db.create_all()

    def tearDown(self):
        db.session.remove()
        db.drop_all()
```

`test/test_app.py:`

```py
from models import TestModel
from test import BaseTestCase
from database import db


test_model = TestModel()


class TestApp(BaseTestCase):
    """WebpageEnricherController integration test stubs"""

    def _add_to_db(self, record):
        db.session.add(record)
        db.session.commit()
        self.assertTrue(record in db.session)

    def test_first(self):
        """
        This test runs perfectly fine
        """
        self._add_to_db(test_model)
        result = db.session.query(TestModel).first()
        self.assertIsNotNone(result, 'Nothing in the database')

    def test_second(self):
        """
        This test runs fine in isolation, but fails if run consecutively
        after the first test
        """
        self._add_to_db(test_model)
        result = db.session.query(TestModel).first()
        self.assertIsNotNone(result, 'Nothing in the database')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import unittest
    unittest.main()
```

So, I can run `TestApp.test_first` and `TestApp.test_second` fine if run in isolation. If I run them consecutively, the first test passes, but the second test fails with:

```
=================================== FAILURES ===================================
_____________________________ TestApp.test_second ______________________________

self = <test.test_app.TestApp testMethod=test_second>

    def test_second(self):
        """
        This test runs fine in isolation, but fails if run consecutively
        after the first test
        """
        self._add_to_db(test_model)
        result = db.session.query(TestModel).first()
>       self.assertIsNotNone(result, 'Nothing in the database')
E       AssertionError: unexpectedly None : Nothing in the database
```

Something is going wrong in the database setup and teardown, but I cannot figure out what. How do I set this up correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is that you are leaking state between one test and the next by reusing a single `TestModel` instance defined once in the module scope (`test_model = TestModel()`).

The state of that instance at the commencement of the first test is `transient`:

> an instance that’s not in a session, and is not saved to the database;
>   i.e. it has no database identity. The only relationship such an object
>   has to the ORM is that its class has a mapper() associated with it.

The state of the object at commencement of the second test is `detached`:

> Detached - an instance which corresponds, or previously corresponded,
>   to a record in the database, but is not currently in any session. The
>   detached object will contain a database identity marker, however
>   because it is not associated with a session, it is unknown whether or
>   not this database identity actually exists in a target database.
>   Detached objects are safe to use normally, except that they have no
>   ability to load unloaded attributes or attributes that were previously
>   marked as “expired”.

This kind of interdependence between tests is almost always a bad idea. You could use [`make_transient()`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.session.make_transient) on the object at the end of every test:

```py
class BaseTestCase(TestCase):
    ...
    def tearDown(self):
        db.session.remove()
        db.drop_all()
        make_transient(test_model)
```

Or you should construct a new `TestModel` instance for each test:

```py
class BaseTestCase(TestCase):
    ...
    def setUp(self):
        db.create_all()
        self.test_model = TestModel()


class TestApp(BaseTestCase):
    ...
    def test_xxxxx(self):
        self._add_to_db(self.test_model)
```

I think the latter is the better choice as there is no danger of any other leaky state getting carried between tests.